# Julia: Creating local variables on workers in parallel context

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Using DistributedArrays in cases when the worker only needs to store unshared data seems overly complicated. I would like to do

```
r=remotecall(2,a=Float64[])
remotecall(2,setindex!,a,5,10) #Error
```

or

```
r=remotecall(2,zeros,10)
remotecall(2,setindex!,r,5,10) #Error.
```

I would like to do this for each worker and then access the array in an async context. Perform some computations and then fetch the results. I am not sure of this is possible because of the  [let behavior of async](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/julia-users/async%7Csort:date/julia-users/YDxPRQhygAA/TGrtucNB7ZwJ)

Below I have made an simplified example for which I modified [the pmap example form the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/parallel-computing/). T

```
times=linspace(0.1,2.0,10) # times in secs representing different difficult computations
sort!(times,rev=true)

np = nprocs()
n = length(times)

#create local variables
for p=1:np
    if p != myid() || np == 1
        remotecall(p,stack = Float64p[]) #does not work
    end
end

@everywhere function fun(s)
    mid=myid()
    sleep(s)
    #s represents some computation save to local stack
    push!(stack,s)
end




#asynchronously do the computations
@everywhere i = 1
function nextidx()
    global i
    idx=i;
    i+=1;
    return idx;
end
@sync begin
    for p=1:np
        if p != myid() || np == 1
            @async begin
                j=1
                res=zeros(40);
                while true
                    idx = nextidx()
                    if idx > n
                        break
                    end
                    remotecall(fun, times[idx])
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

# collect the results of the computations
for p=1:np
    if p != myid() || np == 1
        tmpStack=fetch(p,stack)
        #do someting with the results
    end
end
```

Comment: If all the workers are using the same processing function, why doesn't `pmap` suffice?

Comment: For two reasons 1) it seems that if the function has random runtime pmap is inefficient 2) it might be that aggregate computations on the go say through summing the results on each worker and then summing the indermediate results after all computations have finished.

Comment: And `@parallel` won't work for you either?

Comment: I would like to have more control. E.g. only let calculations run for time t. This would not be possilbe with @parallel.

Answer (score 2):

By using 'global' when you modify the global variable of the worker (e.g., set by @everywhere a = 3), you may be able to resolve your problem. Check out the example code below.

```
@everywhere a = 0
remotecall_fetch(2, ()->a)  # print 0

@everywhere function change_a(b)
    global a
    a = b
end

b = 10
remotecall_fetch(2, change_a, b) 
remotecall_fetch(2, ()->a)  # print 10
```